# flutter ignores button and executes function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I develop an application that has several buttons for each action and to have a more ordered code I wrote a function to have a button:

```
Widget addButton(String msg,Function f){
return  Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: 40,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            height: double.maxFinite,
            color: Colors.blue,
            //icon: Icons.add,
            child: Text('${msg}',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: () {
              f;
            },
          ),
        );
```

}

This function receive a string that show in the button and a function that will be executed when the button is pressed.

When the user writes in a textField (tipoParc.text) it is saved in a map when pressing the button and show in the app, The function in charge of making the application state change is:

```
 addMedicion(){
 setState(() {
      print('cambiando ${tipoParc} con ${selOption} \n');
      medicionTipe[tipoParc.text]=selOption;
    });
```

}

So that everything works in the main code I call the addButton function like this:

```
   addButton('hello',addMedicion())
```

but this does not work when pressing the addButton button, on the contrary when the user writes in textField (typeParc.text) the addMedicion () function is always executed showing the string without pressing the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should define the function signature more precise. Instead of `addButton(String msg, Function f)` do it like this: `addButton(String msg, void Function() f)` (depending on your required return value and parameters).

Second, you don't need to define a function that just calls a function except the function signatur is different. Do it like this:

```dart
Widget addButton(String msg, void Function() f) {
return  Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: MaterialButton(
            // more params
            onPressed: f,
            // onPressed: () => f(), ALTERNATIVE
          ),
        );
}
```

If your function signature is different (i.ex the function need the `context` to execute it's actions), you can do it like this:

```dart
Widget addButton(String msg, void Function(BuildContext context) f) {
return  Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: MaterialButton(
            // more params
            onPressed: () => f(context),
          ),
        );
}
```

Finally, you should just pass the name of the function to the method without the braces. Instead of calling `addButton('hello', addMedicon())`, call `addButton('hello', addMedicon)`.

Last but not least, the [MaterialButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton-class.html) is obsolete. Use RawMaterialButton or some of the implementations (FlatButton, OutlinedButton, RaisedButton). For more details check the documentation under the link.